# Isometry from $\mathbb R^m$ to a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ be a basis of a subspace $U$ of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$ be an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb R^m$. Is there a canonical way to obtain a linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^m\to U\subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $\{Tv_1,\dots,Tv_m\}$ is an orthogonal basis of $U$ without using an orthogonal basis for $U$ a priori?

For example is there a linear map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $2x+3y+4z=0$ which preserves an orthogonal basis?

Comment: Not sure if that's what you have in mind, but you could orthonormalize $\{w_1, \ldots, w_m\}$ via Gram-Schmidt and then construct your map explicitely

Comment: Yes of course. But that's exactly what I don't want. Hence I said without using an orthogonal basis for U a priori.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following come under the criteria "without using an orthogonal basis for $U$ a priori"? Consider any basis $B$ of $U$ and then using Gram Schmidt, get an orthogonal basis $B'$. Then, just map $w_i$s to distinct elements of $B'$.

Comment: Unfortunately Gram Schmidt is precisely the thing I wished to exclude when I wrote "without using an orthogonal basis for U a priori".